# Programmatically Check/Uncheck checkboxes of SSRS Multi-value Parameter

Tags: service, reporting-services, reporting, multivalue

I have a report in SSRS 2005 that has a Multi-value parameter.  When you run the report, is it possible to programmatically check or uncheck the checkboxes depending on what checkbox you check?  In other words, is there a way to have event code run when you check or uncheck the checkboxes?

Mike

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to set range of values of Parameter B depends of selected value of Parameter A. It is named a cascading parameters.

1. Create Parameter A and set list of values for it - for example, the table Continents.
2. Create Parameter B and set next stored procedure as list of avaliable values:

   ```
   CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[countries](@continent int)
   AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   SELECT * FROM countries WHERE id IN
      (SELECT country_id FROM continents WHERE continent_id = @continent)
   ```
3. On the properties of Parameter B (Tab - Parameters) set the first Parameter A to link our parameters together.

Comment: What I was hoping for was to have a single parameter (multi-select) where the items in the list did not change, but whether each item was checked or not could be set depending on what you have checked.

Comment: What actually I am trying to do is this: I have one of the choices as 'All', which is the default. Then if I click on any individual items (to check them), I want the 'All' selection to be unchecked.